# How to pass array in Mail Function in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, function, email

Below is my mail function:
How to can I pass an array to mail function?

```
public function mail(Request $request , $id) {

      $data=[
        'owner'=>MyRoom::where('id',$id)->get(),
        'data2'=>$request->all(),
      ];
      Mail::send('emails.mail' , $data, function($message) use ($data){
        $message->to($owner->created_by->email , $owner->created_by->name)
                ->subject('Room showing Request From OpenRoomList');
        $message->from('regmibipin13@gmail.com','OpenRoomList');
      });
      echo "Email Send check your inbox";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly instead of doing get which will give you a collection, do :

```
'owner' => MyRoom::find($id);
```

In your `resources/emails/mail.blade.php` blade file you can directly use `$owner` and `$data2` variables using blde syntax like : `{{ $owner->somecolumn }}` and `{{ $data2['somefield'] }}`

Comment: Is all other things rather than that is okkay ??

Comment: Yes other things seem okay. Are you still facing problem ?